# Optimizing the load of numerous images

Tags: html, performance, css, optimization, css-sprites

I have a website that displays about 30 fairly small color gif files on the main page. When looking into optimizing the site, I ran Google's PageSpeed Analyzer. It suggests that I create a CSS sprite for them. The problem that I'm running into is that the main page does not show the same 30 images per user and/or per page load. Also, the images are replaced about once a month.

I was thinking maybe a dynamic generation of a CSS sprite or a CSS sprite that contains all possible images. I am looking for the most efficient way of accomplishing this.So my question is, What can I do to reduce the requests or optimize this aspect while allowing for the change described?

Comment: Already, a similar question answered here.
Please find this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145614/generating-css-sprites-for-dynamic-images

Comment: Thank you, I think this will work!